# How to call synchronous code after asynchronous

Tags: javascript

I have a function `sumFileSizes()` that takes the names of two files and calls the function passed in the third parameter and passes it the sum of their sizes as the first argument.
There is an asynchronous function to get the file ramzer `getFileSize()` .

```
function getFileSize(filename, cb) {
  setTimeout(() => cb(fileSizes[filename]), Math.random() * 500);
}

function sumFileSizes(filename1, filename2, cb) {
    const sum = getFileSize(filename1, cb) + getFileSize(filename2, cb);
    setTimeout(cb(sum), Math.random() * 550)
}
```

How to call a callback after processing `const sum = getFileSize(filename1, cb) + getFileSize(filename2, cb);` ?

Comment: By putting the rest of the code _inside_ of the callback. In this case, you'd need `getFileSize(filename1, ...)` and inside of that callback you put `getFileSize(filename2, ...)` and inside of _that_ callback you put the `setTimeout`. Or better (simpler, more stable and less confusing), rewrite your code to use `async`/`await`.

Comment: you should have a look to the await/async keywords, your getFileSize function should return a Promise, resolving with the expected value. On the other hand, the sumFileSizes should be an async function, where you can wait for the getFileSize to resolve withe the await keyword.

Comment: getFileSize does not even return anything

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to combine asynchronous calls with synchronous in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559207/how-to-combine-asynchronous-calls-with-synchronous-in-javascript)

Comment: @CherryDT no need to use async await. I think this option will work =>   `getFileSize(filename1, () => {
        getFileSize(filename2, () => {
            cb(filename1 + filename2)
        })
    })`                                                                                                                              
    but how to keep the sum?

Comment: As you just saw, it's then still convoluted and you didn't figure out a full solution yet  So yes, no _need_ to use a word processor for writing a book, you can also use a typewriter and some correction fluid... but... you may waste your time and energy trying to do it right, with better alternatives available...

Answer (score 0):

Use promises, await/async

```js
// Work to do
const work = (param) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // Do some time consuming stuff
    setTimeout(() => {
      // When done, resolve
      resolve(param * param);
    }, 3000);
  });
}

// Run async function
(async () => {
  // Run worker and wait till finish
  const result = await work(3);
  
  // Use result
  const finalResult = result * 2;
  
  // Log
  console.log(finalResult);
})();
```

Comment: @Tapx I do not need to use async/await. You just need to call a callback after a `setTimeout()`

Answer (score 0):

You can `promisify` your code and then use `async..await`.

```js
function getFileSize(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve((fileSizes[filename])), Math.random() * 500);
  });
}

async function sumFileSizes(filename1, filename2) {
    const size1 = await getFileSize(filename1, cb);
    const size2 = await getFileSize(filename2, cb);
    return size1 + size2;
}
```

Note that async function returns a `promise` so you need to do something like this:

```js
sumFileSize(filename1, filename2).then(cb); // cb is callback function
```

Also note that `async..await` is a new feature and will not support in older browsers. You might have to use a transpiler like `babel` to transform code in ES5.

Comment: I do not need to use async/await. You just need to call a callback after a `setTimeout()`

Answer (score -1):

```
getFileSize(filename1, (value1) => {
    getFileSize(filename2, (value2) => {
      callback(value1 + value2)
    })
})
```